# Why is "our daily lives" "unser tägliches Leben", but "in our daily lives" is "in unserem täglichen Leben"?

Tags: english-to-german

I don't understand why "unser" changes to "unserem" and why "tägliches" changes to "täglichen".

Why do those two words get suffixes because of "in"?

Answer (score 15):

Note German is using [*cases*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case) (Nominative, Accusative, Genitive, Dative) and *unser tägliches Leben* is **nominative**.

*in unserem täglichen Leben* is a **dative** caused by the preposition "in" and thus declined to *unserem täglichen*.

Comment: But this doesn't address the *reason* why. A counterexample with in+accusative would be great.

Comment: @Janka going into long "why" (is there a "why" with grammar?) won't help a user who seems to struggle with the cocept of declension per se?

Comment: *Because it helps distinguishing two different kind of **in**.* – *Because it helps telling apart a third meaning if you missed the initial **in**.*

Comment: @Janka Sometimes it's easy to simply give too much of an answer to beginners. My impression was somewhat along Stephies line: Basic struggles. Thus a concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit bizarre, denizzerde. :-)) *"Why do those two words get suffixes because of "in"?"* There is only **one** 'in' in **one** of your examples, so how could these **two** adjectives depend on **one** 'in'?! :-))  But okay ...

***unser tägliches Leben*** can be Nominativ, thus the subject of a sentence, or Akkusativ, thus an object of a sentence. The grammatical form of the isolated strcuture does not show what it is or will be.

a) [N = wer oder was?] Unser tägliches Leben ist ein einziger Kampf.

b) [A = wen oder was?) Unser tägliches Brot gib uns heute. (Lord's Prayer) -> Wir versuchen, unser tägliches Leben so gut wie möglich zu meistern.

*unser tägliches Leben* sticks to all the rules you know.

*da**s** neue Haus / ein neue**s** Haus / mein neue**s** Haus, dein neue**s** Haus, ... unser neue**s** Haus*

***in unserem täglichen Leben*** answers the question 'wann' or maybe 'wo', thus it's an adverbial phrase. It sticks to all the rules you know.

c) [wann?] *... in eine**m** halbe**n** Jahr ...*

d) [wo?] *... in eine**m** moderne**n** Land ...*

Thus:

*in unsere**m** tägliche**n** Leben*

That's just it. ;-)

Cheers!